# keeping the test data in json format

Tags: selenium, test-data, json

This is my selenium code.

I am just finish my selenium code. I'm following page object pattern. My code does not follow any frameworks.

> 1). I want to  keep the test data separately. Not scattering all over
>   the script. Keep the test data in Json. And read it from there where
>   ever it is necessary.

How to write the code in json format ? Anybody please help me
How to generate the code in json format? compare with above mentioned code

Pageobject

```
package pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;


public class HomePage {
    @FindBy(how= How.NAME, using = "username")
    WebElement username;
    @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using = "password")
    WebElement password;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id=\'login-container\']/form/div[3]/div/p/input[1]" )
    WebElement button;

    //enter  username
    public void  userLogin(String user, String pass)
    {
        username.sendKeys(user);
        password.sendKeys(pass);
        button.click();
    }

}
```

steps

```
package steps;


import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import pageobjects.ClientPage;
import pageobjects.HomePage;

import util.DriverManager;


public class LoginSteps {

    public HomePage Login(String nam, String pas) {
        HomePage homePageObj = PageFactory.initElements(DriverManager.driver, HomePage.class);
        homePageObj.userLogin(nam,pas);

        return homePageObj;
    }


}
```

util

```
package util;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;



public class DriverManager {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl="//http:qms";
    public DriverManager()
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/naveen/chromedriver");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

}
```

test

login

```
 package login;



    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.*;

    import pageobjects.HomePage;
    import steps.LoginSteps;
    import util.DriverManager;


    import static util.DriverManager.driver;

    public class loginTest
    {
        @BeforeSuite(groups = {"regression"})
        public void initDriver(){
            DriverManager manager = new DriverManager();
        }


        @DataProvider(name= "login")
        public static java.lang.Object[][] loginData(){

            return new Object[][]{{"geoso","1"},{"ges","2"},{"geo","1"}};
        }
        @Test(dataProvider = "login")
        public void verifyValidLoginWithDataProvider(String userName,String password)
        {
            LoginSteps loginSteps= new LoginSteps();
            HomePage ex=loginSteps.Login(userName,password);
            Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Hello Naveen"));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - Your JSON is wrong because you a trying to create a list using a key-value syntax, in the outer-most level. The first level should be a dictionary, with a list as value.

```
{
 "geos":

  [
   {"u":"geos","p":"1"},

   {"u":"ges","p":"2"},

   {"u":"geo","p":"1"}

  ]

}
```

Read about JSON format [here](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/json/). A Java JSON reader can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp001.htm#BABEECIB).

2 - You must be careful to not fall in the trap of accessing the JSON file in your tests. You should create:

- An interface (and an implementation class) that models the data; with method like *getListOfGeoLocations*

  Any change in the JSON file structure can be updated directly in the class.
- Create a [factory](http://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/) for that reads from the file and creates instance of this data model class.

  This way, any change in the files/folder organization or the way of creating the data model objects can be update directly in the factory.

Your tests should depend only on the interface.

Comment: Hai.. Can you please provide the code of how to keep test data in  json ?

Comment: still I  am not getting. in the above mentioned which class should I add interface

Comment: Checkout this tutorial on coding-decoding JSON with Java: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: The interface serves to make your tests dependent upon an abstraction, not a concrete class - as I said, this will make your code more resilient to different formats of JSON. The interface would determine methods to get specific data - getListOfGeoLocations, e.g. - and the concrete classes would know how to parse a specific JSON structure to retrieve this data.

Comment: @AntonyNaveen I think you should make separated question; I'll keep an eye on the newest question and try to answer you right away.

Comment: @ JoãoGFarias     http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24949/keeping-the-test-data-in-json-format   please answer to  my question

Comment: @toastmaster What are your doubts about the structure that I described?